# Singleton with context as a variable - memory leaks?

Tags: java, android

I am building a class to handle an app shared preferences. I want to make it singleton accessed from all parts of the project. I can't use the regular getInstance method as I need to pass a context for the class to be functional. I thought of passing a context in the MainActivity.java and than have it constantly there. Will there be memory leaks?

**This is my current solution:**

```
public class LocalStorage {

    private Context context;

    private static LocalStorage instance = null;

    protected LocalStorage() {
        // Exists only to defeat instantiation.
    }

    public static LocalStorage getInstance() {
        if(instance == null) {
            instance = new LocalStorage();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public static LocalStorage getInstance(Context _context) {
        LocalStorage localStorage = getInstance();
        localStorage.context = _context.getApplicationContext();
        return localStorage;
    }

    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences() {
        return context.getSharedPreferences("mySettings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
 ....
```

Answer (score 13):

You will not create a leak since you are only keeping a reference to the application context by calling `getApplicationContext()`.

If you referenced `_context` directly and that reference happened to be an `Activity` or some other `Context` then yes you would have created a memory leak.

As a side note the implementation of the Singleton here is a bit odd. I would suggest the following to remove the unnecessary extra `getInstance()` by passing in the `Context` to the constructor:

```
public class LocalStorage {
    private static LocalStorage instance = null;

    private Context context;

    private LocalStorage(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public synchronized static LocalStorage getInstance(Context context) {
        if(instance == null) {
            instance = new LocalStorage(context.getApplicationContext());
        }

        return instance;
    }

    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences() {
        return context.getSharedPreferences("mySettings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
    ....
```

Comment: Thank you. Regarding the code sample, this would mean I would always need to supply a context with getInstance. I want to only do it once.

Comment: I see. Problem with only doing it once is you have to guarantee that code runs first before any other `getInstance()` calls that do not supply a `Context` or else you will initialize your singleton without a `Context`. That is error prone. It typically isn't an issue to get access to a `Context` whenever you need one. Especially the application context.

Comment: How about setting the context of the singleton on the application class' onCreate method? wouldn't it always run first? are there any caveats in doing so?

Comment: That should be fine if you really want to go that route. However, note that the way the `getInstance()` method that takes a context is currently written it is not a Singleton. It never assigns the static `instance`. Also if you ever accidentally call getInstance(...) with a `Context` again you break the contract of the singleton since it is not checking/returning an existing instance if one was already created.

Comment: Doesn't it? it calls the other getInstance on the first line.

Comment: Yes it does. Missed the call to `getInstance()` instead of `new LocalStorage()` this time around.